# Create buttons side by side dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following method which I call a few times to create a list of buttons. It works well and creates the buttons.

```
public void CreateButton(int i) {
    LinearLayout btnLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btnLayout);
    Button btn = new Button(this);

    btn.setId(i);
    btn.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));
    btnLayout.addView(btn);
}
```

But each created button is fitting the screen in width, and I would want it to stay side by side, two buttons per row. I managed to set the button to half the screen size using this:

```
int displaywidth= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels; 
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((int)(displaywidth/2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

It makes the button's width to be half the screen's size, but I can't figure out how to place them side by side. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `orientation` in your `LinearLayout` to `horizontal`.

```
<LinearLayout
...
   android:orientation="horizontal"
... >
   ...
</LinearLayout>
```

If you only have a single `LinearLayout` that is to hold multiple side-by-side buttons you can make horizontal `LinearLayout`s to hold your button pairs and either nest them in the main `veritical` layout or utilize another layout, for example `RelativeLayout`, to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks... I've mantained the main `LinearLayout` as vertical, and added to my loop the creation of a Horizontal oriented layout on each two buttons, and used it to wrap each set of two buttons. It worked like a charm.... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using weight property of LinearLayout. If in each row you want only two buttons then give

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

to LinearLayout and

```
android:layout_weight="0.5"
```

to each button or you can set weight dynamically in your code by

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, xf);
```

where x represents the float value of layout weight of your button.
for more details about layout weight http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is by using their weight and width. Make sure the Linear Layout has a horizontal orientation. Then, use Layout_params to set their width to "Wrap_Content" and their weight to "1". Then both will automatically take up the same amount of space.